# Best Tactics for jQuery Animations

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I've really tried to understand if jQuery queue() is the way to go for this or not -- but basically I'm trying to create more of a "storyline" with certain jQuery animations. Example http://jsfiddle.net/93Nyz/

Basically, the goal here is to load in data based on a certain time delay... and then go on to the next, etc. I'm just wondering if there is a more efficient way of writing this. It seems like in theory if this was a huge, constant animation that "delay" value would get pretty large (compared to the initial 1000 delay). Wondering if there's a "delay+500" or something like that, so it inherits the previous delays value. If so, also wondering if the original way I wrote that animation makes sense for other, regular uses. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what `queue()` was made for. What you probably want to do is break up your animations into functions, and then chain them together using queue.

I forked your fiddle (heh) to show you an example: http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/MVbn9/

Comment: Really awesome stuff - thank you very much, I really appreciate it and actually understand!

Answer (score 1):

Personnaly, i would do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/93Nyz/1/
This way, all animations can have a fixed delay

Comment: Thanks for the input - really nice to see some alternative examples for this!